# Limiting the Highcharts x Axis while the chart extending During Ajax Drill Down

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts

I created highcharts, where I am Drill down using Ajax, so if i click the xAxis label, I passed the xAxis label value via Ajax and I will load the new data in the series accordingly sometimes I ll also change the charts like spline -> column and column->waterfall like wise

But now the problem is, I set a date picker for the dashboard, as default I ll show the data for 3 months *Mar-2014, Apr-2014, May-2014*, so incase if users pick dates from Jan-2013 - Aug-2014, the series and data labels get overlapped and chart looks ugly

So my chart sometimes shows only 1 month of data or sometimes more than 2 years of data as per the user picks, so now i need to limit the number of x axis just to 8 months , so if the user picks more than 8 months also i need to show only 8 months of data

Example 1: Looks Fine
[image]

Example 2: Looks Ugly

[image]

I tried of implementing

minRange:4 inside the xAxis i end up with this

Example3: Showing the array value

[image]

Sorry for not posting any fiddle or examples as data is huge and everything works in AJAX like date picker and drill down everything

Almost i tried of many external jquery functions also as mentioned in some posts in stack overflow somewhat related to my chart, but none seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`xAxis.ceiling`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.ceiling). Set it to `7` (categories starts from 0) and that should resolve your issue.